# Removing RelativeLayout.END_OF which is added programmatically ,android 5.0 I can‘t but android 8 I can

Tags: android

the RelattiveLayout.END_OF which is added programmatically but can't remove. Atv first it can be effected,but second it doesn't.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mBtnDownload.getLayoutParams();
    if (visible) {
        params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, R.id.hidden_view);
        params.leftMargin = ResourceUtils.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_normal_6);
    } else {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF);
        params.leftMargin = 0;
    }
    mBtnDownload.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: you are asking to remove END_OF but actually in code you are removing RIGHT_OF

Comment: sorry,I edit it

Comment: Try to refresh the view after setting the layout params, `invalidate()`

Comment: in fact , setLayoutParams  it will call requestLayout, so I think call invalide() will be useless OK, i try